# JS Sequelize "Where Related" Query?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm not sure how to perform a specific type of query.

Not sure what the Sequelize community might call it, but the Codeigniter PHP framework calls it a "where_related" query.

For example, let's say I have 2 object types:  hotelRoom and roomStyle.

hotelRoom has the property roomNumber, and related roomStyle objects.

Let's say I want to find all roomStyle objects that are related to hotelRoom objects having roomNumber < 200

Can Sequelize do this without resorting to raw SQL?

Comment: Why the immediate down vote?  Seems like a reasonable question that I don't see answered elsewhere.

Comment: Didn't downvote but the question is not very clear. There are 5 tags and no code... See if this helps http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @user3105482 likely downvoted due to lack of code... that being said I am also starting out with sequelize and having trouble finding documentation for certain query types... so I'm just doing raw SQL for now, then will probably move them into SPROCs for the more complicated ones.

Comment: The question is less of a 'fix this' question than one which asks if Sequelize can even do what I'm trying to do.  My thought was that code would just serve to complicate the question.  Thanks for the feedback though

Comment: [See if this post helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358989/sequelize-problem-getting-associations-to-return).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [eager loading](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/models#eager-loading) and [one-to-many](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/associations#one-to-many) associations.

```
var HotelRoom = sequelize.define('HotelRoom', { roomNumber: DataType.INTEGER })
,   RoomStyle  = sequelize.define('RoomStyle');

// this will add the HotelRoomId column to RoomStyle table
HotelRoom.hasMany(RoomStyle);

// create an instance of room and make it the parent of a style
HotelRoom.create({ roomNumber: 5 })
.then(function(room){
  return RoomStyle.create()
  .then(function(style){
    room.addStyle(style)
  })
})
```

Then you can use eager loading methods to return all room styles for a range of room numbers.

```
RoomStyle.findAll({ 
  include: [{ 
    model: HotelRoom, 
    attributes: [], 
    where: { roomNumber: { lt: 200 } } // i.e. "less than 200"
  }] 
})
.then(function(res){ 
  console.log(res) 
});
```

That all assumes that the relationship between rooms and styles is one to many. To define a many-to-many relationship, just define the relationship going back in the other direction (the above code will still work).

```
// define a many-to-many relationship through the junction table "RoomsStyles"
HotelRoom.hasMany(RoomStyle, { through: RoomsStyles });
RoomStyle.hasMany(HotelRoom, { through: RoomsStyles });
```

Cheers, hope this is helpful.